# How do I figure out what's wrong with Register-ScheduledTask parameter sets?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a (unfortunately) very, very long PowerShell script that builds out an entire server instance.  That is: all files are installed, all system settings are added, and so on.  The last thing it does is add a scheduled task to run the "master" program when the computer boots.  However, I'm getting an error from `Register-ScheduledTask` and I really can't see what's wrong.  This is my FIRST PowerShell script.

I've played with passing different parameters, like not using `-InputObject` and using the individual subset objects.  I've removed some of the extra parameters (like `-Description`, `-Password`, `-RunLevel`, etc) but always get the same result (except not passing any info gives an error that there is no action, of course).

```
$INSTALL = "C:\PPC\MCPSuite" # hardcoded for example
$TASKPWD = "1234567890" # ditto
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "${INSTALL}\MCPSuite.exe" -WorkingDirectory "$INSTALL"
$owner = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "dnpapps" -LogonType "Password" -RunLevel "Highest"
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -StartWhenAvailable -ExecutionTimeLimit (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 0) -Priority 4
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Principal $owner -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "PPC-MCPSuite-Test" -Description "MCP Suite Manager" -InputObject $task -Password "$TASKPWD" -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

Here is the error message:

```
Register-ScheduledTask : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Users\levy\MCP-Installer\MCPv2\task.ps1:14 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "PPC-MCPSuite-Test" -Description "MC ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Register-ScheduledTask], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Register-ScheduledTask
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message, `Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.` means that the parameters consist an incorrect combination. Let's [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps).

You are using `-InputObject`, and it's defined in one of the four signatures available like so:

```
Register-ScheduledTask
        [-Force]
        [-InputObject] <CimInstance>
        [[-Password] <String>]
        [[-User] <String>]
        [[-TaskName] <String>]
        [[-TaskPath] <String>]
        [-CimSession <CimSession[]>]
        [-ThrottleLimit <Int32>]
        [-AsJob]
        [<CommonParameters>]
```

You are also using `-Description`, which doesn't exist in the signature above. However, it's available in two different signatures, neither of those support `-InputObject`. Since the arguments don't match, Powershell throws you the error above.

To fix the issue, call the cmdlet with valid set of parameters. Since `-InputObject $task` seems to contain task settings, pass the description within it. Maybe something like so,

```
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Principal $owner -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings -Description "MCP Suite Manager" 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "PPC-MCPSuite-Test" -InputObject $task -Password "$TASKPWD" -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

Comment: My newness to PowerShell was what got me.  I did somehow figure this out that those different "parameter sets" was being referred to, so I strictly followed one and it worked!  But thanks for answering/confirming.

Comment: @BretLevy If you are familiar with [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) in languages such as C++, C# and Java, the parameter sets are pretty much same concept.